# no matching function for call to... missing overload in inherited C++ class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

Can someone please explain what's going on here. Why can't the compiler see hello() with no arguments in class A?

```
struct A {
    virtual void hello() {}
    virtual void hello(int arg) {}
};
struct B : A {
    virtual void hello(int arg) {}
};

int main()
{
    B* b = new B();
    b->hello();
    return 0;
}
```

g++ main.cpp

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:13:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::hello()’
main.cpp:13:11: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:7:15: note: virtual void B::hello(int)
main.cpp:7:15: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: needed argument, read what compiler is giving u

Comment: Because in inheritance only name is considered, not full prototype.

Comment: The base class one doesn't get considered when there's one already in the derived class unless you add a using statement to pull it in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your overriding of `hello(int arg)` hides other functions with the same name.

What you can do is to explicitly introduce those base class functions to subclass:

```
struct B : A {
    using A::hello; // Make other overloaded version of hello() to show up in subclass.
    virtual void hello(int arg) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a function called `hello` in the derived class *hides* all functions with the same name in the base class. You can unhide them with a using declaration:

```
struct B : A {
    using A::hello;
    virtual void hello(int arg) {}
};
```

or access them via a base-class pointer or reference:

```
static_cast<A*>(b)->hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `hello(int)` member function in `B` takes an int argument and hides the `hello()` member of `A`. If you want the `hello` member function of `B` not to hide the one in `A`, add `using A::hello` to `B`.